# Why I can't use Shell method in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I see everyone is using the Shell command without any problem, but it doesn't work for me, it says it's not declared like it doesn't exist. I'm working in Visual Studio using VB.NET.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: You say you "see everyone" using this - could you possible link to (a/some) example(s)?

Comment: Of course:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b252f11-2e40-4139-8669-8de45ab9e141/how-to-run-and-open-an-access-2016-database-from-vbnet-2015?forum=vbgeneral

https://www.toolbox.com/tech/programming/question/reference-to-open-microsoft-access-database-from-visualbasicnet-120210/

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell?view=net-5.0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7zYt9ICMPY

Comment: `Shell` is a valid command in VB.Net, so regardless of where the code came from this should work - docs -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell

Comment: @dlico23 Which version of Visual Studio are you using, and what version of VB.Net please?

Comment: @Martin Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 v 16.6.2 and I'm trying to check the VB.NET version

Comment: @Heinzi I added `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` at the top of the code, but the problem still remains...

Comment: Strange, that [should work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8iSq8a). Do you get the exact same error after adding that Imports statement?

Comment: Yes, and Visual studio told me that it was an unnecessary import because it was already included

Comment: Does the error also show up if you compile your project and check the compilation output? Sometimes, IntelliSense sees errors that aren't there...

Comment: Perhaps theres another method called Shell in an imported namespace? (got bitten by that before)

Comment: If you simplify the line to Shell("") does the error change? Wondering if the quotes inside quotes is confusing intellisense..

Answer (score 2):

[`Interaction.Shell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell?view=net-5.0) is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, which *should* automatically be imported for Visual Basic projects.

If it isn't in yours, you can fix that in the project properties (Tab "References") or manually add `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` at the top of the code file.

Another possible reason is that Interaction.Shell is not included in .NET Core versions prior to 5. In that case, use a "classic" .NET Framework project or .NET 5 or higher instead. (Credit to Hans Passant in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated the app, without change anything and now it works... In any case, thank you to everybody for the support.

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).